# Ruby Pointers/Reference

Tags: ruby

```
require 'csv'

class Apple
    def initialize()
        @num = CSV.read("Location", :headers=>false)
        #assume @num[0][0] has 'A1D'
    end
    def Display()
        puts @num[0][0]
    end
    def Problem()
        temp = @num[0][0]
        temp['D'] = "A"
    end
end

ap = Apple.new
ap.Display
ap.Problem
ap.Display
```

Displayed answer
A1D
A1A

When you assign temp to @num[0][0], I don't want any changes happening in @num when I make changes in temp value.

I am not sure how to do this.  Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use just `temp = @num[0][0].dup`. As you did `temp = @num[0][0]`, thus `temp` is pointing to the object, which is `@num[0][0]` giving. Thus any change to the string object pointed by `temp` will affect the string lies in `@num[0][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mutate the original object, you need to make a copy (say, by `dup`). Remember, though, that any instance variables in the dup'ed object will still reference the same objects they did in the original, so you'll need to dup those as well if you want to modify them.